# Retrieve Querystring using VBscript in html

Tags: html, vbscript

localhost/Project.html?ProjectId=P6610C32F-7C54-4221-A190-A9E7E08F8B08

This is my weburl.

I want to retrieve query string value of variable "ProjectId"

How i can do this using vbscript and html page

Comment: Are you wanting to capture this on the server side or within the browser on the client side?

Comment: And you realise this will only work in IE?

Comment: I want it in client side

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite familiar with VBScript but let me show you the idea using javascript; a location.search string will be formatted according to certain rules. For instance, every specific variable contained in the string will be a statement in itself, separated from each other by ampersand "&" characters. Therefore, we can split the location.search string into an array of strings, like this:

```
mySearch = location.search.substr(1).split("&")
```

This creates an array of objects named mySearch. Each will look like this:

```
ProjectId=P6610C32F-7C54-4221-A190-A9E7E08F8B08
```

And you can access the array to get your information.